# Android: Scrolling doesn't go all the way to the bottom

Tags: java, android, android-layout, scroll

I've been struggling to get my toolbar to hide upon scrolling. I've managed to get that sorted, and now I'm stuck with a different issue where when I scroll the last cards in my recyclerview are cut in half. I cannot completely see the last card/cards.

See image here:
[image]

Main activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.paws.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--scrolling view should remain here so the above inherits behavior-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fram"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
```

**Or**

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                if (dy > 0 && bottom_navigation.isShown()) {
                    bottom_navigation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (dy < 0 ) {
                    bottom_navigation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {

                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
        });
```

Better  check it in realdevice.

Comment: Tried the first one with no luck. The second one I cannot do since my bottom navigation is in the main.java and the recyclerview is in the fragment.java

Comment: @DeanLambrechts Take it static variable as a Buttomnavigationview do it in fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to wrap your `BottomNavigationView` and `FrameLayout` inside of `RelativeLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.paws.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!--scrolling view should remain here so the above inherits behavior-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fram"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:align_parent_bottom = "true"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Tried this, then it moves my bottomnavbar to the top below my toolbar...

Comment: Make `FrameLayout` `layout_height` from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`